# android widget on Qt

Tags: android, c++, qt, widget, android-widget

Is it possible to create an Android widget using Qt?

My program shows the time with digital clock (hh/mm/ss) and date and it's working on android as android application.

I'm trying to create an Android widget by editing this program, any idea?

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include <QTime>
#include "dialog.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //showTime();
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer , SIGNAL(timeout()), this , SLOT(showTime()) );
    timer->start();

    QDateTime dateTime =QDateTime::currentDateTime();
    QString datetimetext = dateTime.toString();
    ui->DateTime->setText(datetimetext);

}
void MainWindow::showTime(){
    QTime time = QTime::currentTime();
    QString time_text = time.toString("hh : mm : ss");
    if((time.second()%2)==0){
        time_text[3]=' ';
        time_text[8]=' ';

    }
    ui->Digital_clock->setText(time_text);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Dialog secdialog;
    secdialog.setModal(true);
    secdialog.exec();
}
```

Comment: you can create a normal qt widget - which is coded in C++. And then you can port it to android

Comment: See [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/46175/how-create-android-widget-on-qt)

Comment: You could use android ndk with qtcreator and you can perfectly c++ code compiled to whatever architecture your phone or virtual device has... read this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/androidgs.html

Answer (score 4):

Since all these questions are left unanswered, I'll answer this one. Android widgets cannot currently be done using the Qt framework (nor with other crossplatform technologies such as Phonegap). They have to be pure, native Java applications.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer